# Prevent redirect link to deeplink from opening mobile browser

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, web-development-server

I found that some email clients don't handle deeplinks properly, so the solution was to put a link to an HTTP url in the email, and have a server redirect from that link to the actual deeplink instead.

On iOS, this solution causes the browser to open before finally triggering the deeplink and offering to open my app. However, I just noticed I have an app on my phone which seems to use the same solution, except that it skips the step of opening the browser, even though the link in the email is HTTP.

How can I reproduce the same result where clicking the link in the email redirects to the deeplink without opening the browser in between?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable universal links for your app. Using a service like branch.io might guide you in the right direction. Here's a link to branch io's universal links page: https://branch.io/universal-links/